# College Scorecard: Why are values of the variables in the series " Percent completed within X years at original institution" not strictly ascending?

Tags: collegescorecard

I've been looking at the values of COMP_ORIG_YRX_RT for a subset of schools (4 year schools in MI). I was examining the values of COMP_ORIG_YR8_RT, since that seems to match up with what's used for published graduation rates (is that right?). I would expect that the percent completed within 8 years would be greater than within 6 or 4 for each school. For Aquinas College (the one that caught my eye), the graduation rate on the College Scorecard interface is 58%. Can anyone explain these columns to me? Should I be using a different column for completion rate?

[image: Excerpt of Michigan Schools]